# Core Web Vitals CLS fails, but Page Speed Insights and Lighthose shows CLS = 0

Tags: google-search-console, core-web-vitals

Our website https://blog.servermania.com fails CLS for Core Web Vitals report.

We've fixed it, and currently, Page Speed Insights shows CLS = 0. However, after running validation in Google Search Console, we still got the same CLS issue in Core Web Vitals.

My only guess is that we didn't clear Cloudflare cache before starting the validation, but maybe it's something else? Does anybody have the same problem?

Comment: Are you running a live test in Google Search Console?  Is the metric failing for lab results or field results?

Comment: This is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Please [edit] the question to address the points that need to be clarified, then re-ask it on [webmasters.se] and delete it here.

Answer (score 2):

PageSpeed Insights shows CLS from two environments: real users and lab/synthetic tests. I can confirm that PSI reports your lab CLS is 0.0 for both desktop and mobile:

[image]

However, the real-user CLS does show some issues. One major complication is that there's not enough data for your home page to see any real-user stats, so PSI is falling back to data across all pages on your website (AKA origin). Let's look at the origin-level CLS anyway.

On [desktop](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.servermania.com&form_factor=desktop) it's rated "good" but slightly higher than 0.0:

[image]

0.1 is the threshold after which it's no longer good, so at 0.08 you're getting close to failing the Core Web Vitals assessment.

On [mobile](https://pagespeed.web.dev/report?url=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.servermania.com&form_factor=mobile) things are much different:

[image]

Your mobile users experience a CLS score of 0.32 (at the 75th percentile) which blows past the "good" threshold of 0.1, and into "poor" territory.

The fact that Lighthouse isn't corroborating this with the lab CLS suggests that one of two (or both) things are at play: there are user-dependent factors contributing to poor CLS, or we're not auditing the page with actual CLS issues. For example, if CLS is induced by scrolling or clicking, Lighthouse won't necessarily capture those layout shifts. Also, it's possible that the home page really does have perfect layout stability, and other pages on your website are hurting the origin-level score. I'd suggest testing a few other popular pages to see if the Lighthouse metrics are any different.

In any case, I would highly recommend using the [Web Vitals extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-vitals/ahfhijdlegdabablpippeagghigmibma?hl=en) for Chrome and browsing your website as a regular user would. It can tell you when your pages have poor CLS in real-time, so you would have a much clearer idea of what is causing the shifts.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.

Have a question though, if all pages under blog.servermania.com have 0 CLS, and some pages under www.servermania.com have bad CLS, could they affect blog.servermania.com scores?

Comment: The way Core Web Vitals are aggregated in the Chrome UX Report (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/) is at the page and origin level. Because www and blog are different subdomains, they're considered different origins and CWV will be aggregated separately.

Comment: Well, in this case, I have no idea why the origin level report has CLS issues because I'm pretty sure there's not a single page with CLS.

Comment: I'm able to get a CLS value of 0.77 on your home page with mobile emulation and the Web Vitals extension. I think it has something to do with the two carousels on the page.

Comment: Just to confirm, by the home page you meant: https://blog.servermania.com?
Because I'm not aware of any carousels there :) And I can't reproduce your results.

Comment: Oh no sorry I must have been testing a product/service page. But if you use the extension on any blog post page, you should see a high CLS value on scroll when the chat widget / cookie banner appears.